# Numerical Methods for Linear Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I solve (numerically) the linear equation $AB=0$. where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$?
How much is the computational cost?

Comment: Solve for what? Do you want to find one solution, or all solutions?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.. the matrix B is the unknown matrix while the matrix A is known. I need just a solution B.

Comment: $B=0^{n\times m}$  costs nothing, it's free!

Comment: of course B not $0$. In particular i would like 
$$B = \left[ \matrix{
  {I_n}  \cr 
  X  \cr}  \right]$$ with $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Comment: Your dimensions don't match up. You said that B is nxm, but you now seem to be asking for it to be (n+m)xn.

Comment: I think you are looking for the _nullspace_ of $A$. http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/The-Nullspace-of-a-Matrix.topicArticleId-20807,articleId-20787.html

Comment: The maximum number of columns of $B$ is the dimension of the nullspace of $A$, which is less than $n$ unless $A=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may treat $B$ one column at a time:
\begin{equation} 
B = \Bigg[b_1\;\;b_2\;\;\ldots\;\;b_m\Bigg]
\end{equation}
where the $b_i$ are column vectors of length $n$ (and there are $m$ of them).

If $A$ is invertible, it spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the only solution is $B=0$. Otherwise you are looking for vectors $b_i$ in the nullspace of $A$. Suppose $A$ has rank $r$ (number of independent columns). Then dim N($A$) = n-r. This means that there are $n-r$ independent vectors that give $Ax=0$; these x's form a basis for N($A$). So every matrix $B$ whose columns are linear combinations of these x's will give $AB=0$.

As for computational cost, the effort is in finding a basis for N($A$). Usually this is an operation of order $O(n^2)$.

Reducing $A$ to it's echelon form, the columns which do not look like the identity matrix will contain the basis for the nullspace (in MATLAB this is rref(A) and in Mathematica it is RowReduce[A]).

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to reformulate the equation with the help of the [Kronecker Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product): With the vectorization operator $\mathrm{vec}$ which stacks all columns of a matrix into a large vector it holds that
$$
\mathrm{vec}(ABC) = (C^T\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(B)
$$
and this allows you to reformulate $AB=0$ as a usual linear system for $B$.